# Accessing a layout from adapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new with Android development.

My `activity_main.xml` file contains a **Listview** and wanna put a `TextView` each line of list view. Then I added a new layout file under `layout/` folder to identify my text.
But, I couldn't access the layout and TextView while writing inflate in Adapter class.

Below the piece of Adapter class code.

```
 View lineView;
 lineView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.line_layout, null);
 TextView textView = (TextView) lineView.findViewById(R.id.namesurname);
```

Andy idea why getting compile error with this code?

Comment: What exactly is the error and where you're getting it ?

Comment: compile error that line_layout cannot be resolved or is not a field. I can not access line_layout in my Adapter class

Comment: Make sure you're importing R class of your project not android.R, and that's the one you're referencing.
Also make sure you have automatic build turned on in eclipse because if your project hasn't been built your layout entry won't be projected in your R class

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud. I delete import android.R; and is working now